# MySql view with function call

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a view that string splits a column in an underlying table using a custom function. I also have a where clause on the view definition that limits the rows returned. When I select from the view without a where clause everything works as expected. When I add a where clause on the view itself with a filter on one of the columns produced by the function it seems to not use the inner where clause on the view definition to determine what rows are passed to the function called by the outer where clause.

This is probably best explained with an example. I'm using MariaDB 10.2.11

```
Table T1

ID      Text        Status
1       a,b,c       Completed
2       a,b,c,d     Failed
3       a,b,c       Completed
4       a,b,c       Completed

view C1 defined as 

select id, 
stringsplit(Text,1) as ColA, 
Status 
from T1
where Status = 'Completed';

select * from C1 where ColA = 'a';
```

On the final select I have noticed that data from rows that should have been filtered out by the inner where clause are being passed into the stringsplit function call generated by the outer where ColA = 'a' clause.

I would have expected the inner where on the view to have removed all the rows where Status != 'Completed' before where ColA = 'a' clause kicked in. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then I can't reproduce it, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9f59a239b0e1b27353200dfdd736558f). I used `LEFT` function unlike `stringsplit`, maybe there is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Yes maybe its an issue because its a custom function but its still very strange and unexpected. Its almost like its doing things in the wrong order ie outer where on view followed by inner where in view definition

Comment: Just had a look at your dbfiddle and i dont think i explained the problem very well. The query does produce the correct results. The problem is that the outer where is executed first which is a very costly custom function call and then the inner where is applied after. It has a huge performance impact but produces correct results. Thanks again

Comment: See [View Algorithms](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/view-algorithms/) ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1e8747a8080057dbf84185967ba6f442)) and [23.5.2 View Processing Algorithms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html) ([db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8X9B2DULbzZaKpNrCLLQS2/0)).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It all makes sense now as the default is to merge the where clauses and the query optimiser is executing the outer where first.